# How are strings written down in FlatBuffers

Tags: flatbuffers

I am researching FlatBuffers file structure and I want to know how are strings written down. From what I could gather, the string `orc` (for example) is written down as letters count in little endian (0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0) followed by the actual letters and followed by something else. I am trying to understand what the something else is. What bytes follow the letters? I am only asking about the presentation of this specific string in buffer/file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FlatBuffer documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_internals.html):

> *"Strings are simply a vector of bytes, and are always null-terminated. Vectors are stored as contiguous aligned scalar elements prefixed by a 32bit element count (not including any null termination). Neither is stored inline in their parent, but are referred to by offset. A vector may consist of more than one offset pointing to the same value if the user explicitly serializes the same offset twice."*

Thus, the 4 bytes at the front are the 32 bit element count, and `0x3 0x0 0x0 0x0` would mean that there are 3 bytes in the string excluding zero termination. (FlatBuffer defaults to [little-endian](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html); see link above.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the part regarding the size + characters. What I need to know is the byte[s] after both size + characters. You said null terminated. Reading a guide I saw a `0` right after `orc` and then [unused space]. Is the `0` the null termination? On the string `Goblin` I saw **two** `0`  after the characters. I am trying to understand the 0s and unused space. I want to confirm if the unused space is part of the string presentation or not and also how it is calculated.

Comment: Null termination is done with a zero byte.  Anything after the 0 is not logically part of the string.  It could be padding added for alignment purposes, or uninitialized stuff.  **You really should read the spec for yourself**.   That is all I am doing.

Comment: There's even an encoding example ... which **shows** the padding at the end of a string.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. From what you have said the string `Fred` is null terminated by a '0' followed by 3x `0` as padding. How is that padding calculated exactly. This is my last question and would allow me to have a full understanding of the representation. Thank you.

Comment: The actual bytes use for padding are irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the number of padding bytes. You work out the alignment requirement for the *next* element (per the spec) and then add enough bytes to meet the requirement.  But the other thing to note is that is not a *formal* spec.  It is actually "internal documentation" ... and in some respects it is under-specified.  So to understand exactly how the encoding works you would need to read the source code.

Comment: Take a look at the annotated binary that shows a string and the bytes annotations: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/annotated_binary/annotated_binary.afb#L186-L189